# Assigned global variable issue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodejs-stream

I am trying to upload file in node server.

I am defining uploadedfileName as a global variable. After I am uploading the file at that time I am trying to store file name in to this variable
I want to get the global variable in getResponseWithPython function with the file name

**HTML:**

```
<form id="upload" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**I am defining uploadedfileName as a global variable**

**JS:**

```
** //declartion**
global.uploadedFileName = '';

//upload route
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    var busboy = new Busboy({
        headers: req.headers
    });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        console.log("Context path=" + __dirname);
        var saveTo = path.join(__dirname + "/uploads", filename);

        console.log('Uploading: ' + saveTo);
        file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));

        ** //After I am uploading the file at that time I am trying to store file name in to this variable**
        global.uploadedFileName = filename;

    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('Upload complete');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Connection': 'close'
        });
        res.end("That's all folks!");
    });

    return req.pipe(busboy);

});


function getResponseWithPython(prevMsg, cb) {

    ** // I want to get the global variable in this function with the file name**
    console.log(" global.uploadedFileName::: " + global.uploadedFileName);
    var pythonRes = '';
    var formData = {

        // Pass data via Streams
        input_file: fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/GoogleHeader.csv')

    };
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    var req = request.post({
        url: 'https://google.com:443/classification/',
        formData: formData
    }, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
        console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
        pythonRes = body;

        return cb(pythonRes);
    });

};
```

**Note: I have mentioned comments in the code to understand flow of code and my requirement**

Comment: Where are you calling the `getResponseWithPython` from? Basically if the function is called 'after' the post request, you should see the value on `global.uploadedFileName`. Also note that if there was no file in post request, the 'file' event will never be triggered and you consequently will never assign the filename to global scope.

Comment: @elem4th : Please have a look at my html  and JS   https://gist.github.com/dileephell/059722403525842137a4889652cc80ff and    https://gist.github.com/dileephell/501a7f1e665a1114b27ae9bc7e9617c5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `process.env.uploadedFileName = '';`

I am sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign value during declaration.

```
**//declartion**
global.uploadedFileName;
```

Comment: I have declared global variable as you suggested. But I am getting undefined inside the post request as well as outside. Please look the comment inside the post method